# Check if relation is in BCNF

Tags: normalization, relational-theory

I have the following relation and function dependencies.

```
R = ABCDE
F: C->AB, D->A, BE->CE, E->B
```

I have to check whether this relation is in BCNF.

Wikipedia states:

> ...if and only if for every one of its dependencies X → Y, at least one
> of the following conditions hold:
>
> - X → Y is a trivial functional dependency (Y ⊆ X)
> - X is a superkey for schema R

So first I went on to find the superkeys.

Since D is not on the right side, I'm assuming the superkey must contain D in it.

What I thought is that the only superkey is DE. Is this correct?

And if the only superkey is DE, then the relation **is not** in BCNF because none of the functional dependencies have the superkey on the left.

Can anyone point out if I'm mistaken?

Comment: I guess you mean the `DE` is the only **minimal** superkey. But why isn't `DC` too? How did you get to this result? Why isn't `DB` or `DA` or `DAB` a superkey as well?

Comment: Another question you should consider: is `R` in 3NF? Is it in 2NF? If not, it's surely not in BCNF either.

Comment: DC is not for sure, because CLOSURE(DC, F) = DCAB. I got this result by trying out the combinations DA, DB, DC, DE and finding that only DE is the superkey.

I'm curious whether my way to directly check if this relation is in BCNF is correct (I don't want to test for 3NF/2NF).

Comment: Again; you mean minimal superkey. The whole R `ABCDE` is trivially a superkey, too, so `DE` cannot be the only superkey.

Comment: You're right - but I'm still curious about whether my conclusion that this relation IS NOT in BCNF - based on the fact that the minimal superkey is DE - is correct? Or can checking for BCNF be done differently?

Comment: Yes, you can. If it is in BCNF and the only minimal superkey is `DE`, then the only dependency would be `DE->ABC` (and consequencies).

Comment: If you want to write an answer explaining more in detail, I could accept it.

Comment: Please show all the steps of your work following a textbook. PS This doesn't make sense unless F is a closure, but you don't say that. The BCNF defintion is talking about *all* FDs that hold, but F only contains some of them. But when you show your work trying to following a textbook we can show you how you haven't followed it. But right now you are just asking us to guess how your textbook presents things & guess what you did for each step & rewrite your textbook & not be able to tell you where you went right & wrong & do your homework.

Comment: PS I meant cover, not closure.

Answer (score 3):

"Armstrong's axioms are a set of axioms (or, more precisely, inference rules) used to infer all the functional dependencies on a relational database"([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms)).

- R: ABCDE
- F: C->AB, D->A, BE->CE, E->B

BE->CE can be split in BE->C and BE->E. The trivial functional dependency BE->E can be skipped. BE->C can be replaced by E->C because from BE->C and E->B one can deduce E->C. Therefore the set of functional dependencies can be reduced to:

- R: ABCDE
- F: C->AB, D->A, E->C, E->B

A and B cannot be member of a key because they cannot be found on the left site of a functional dependency. So it is sufficient to search all keys of the relational system (remove the Attributes A B from R and all functional dependencies containing A and B)

- R: CDE
- F: E->C

C is not on the left side of a functional dependcy so again one can reduce the system to

- R: DE
- F:

So the list F of functional identities is empty. The only key of this relational system is DE which is also the only key of the unreduced systems. So your answer of your first question is true.

You can use [this page](http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/kandidatenschluessel.php) to find your candidate keys

To check if the system is in BCNF it is not necessary to find all candidate keys. It is sufficient to find one functional dependency which has a left side that is no a key.

C->AB is such a functional dependency: C is not a key because the closure of C is C. This means that no further attributes can be generated by applying functional dependencies on C.

You can use [this page](http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/normalformen.php) to find check if a relation is in normal form.

Comment: But the question does not say that the given set of FDs is a cover; you are unjustifiably assuming it. So although Armstrong's axioms tell us that further FDs hold because the given ones do, we don't know whether any other FDs hold, so we don't know CKs or highest NF.